# Update attachBaseContext in MainActivity.java from a fragment

Tags: java, android

How can I update attachBaseContext in MainActivity from a fragment? E.g.

MyFragment.java

```
String chosenLanguage = "en";

public void updateLanguage(String chosenLanguage) {
    //...Update MyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase, chosenLanguage) here
}
```

MainActivity.java (Following succesfully calls a java class and changes app language)

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(MyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase,"en"));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to restart activity to run 'attachBaseContext' again.

In your fragment run:

Intent intent= new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);